# Understanding “später ist dann nichts mehr daraus geworden”

Tags: expletiva, subject

The question is on the highlighted clause in this passage from the translation of Camus’s *The Stranger* by Georg Goyert and Hans Georg Brenner.

> Ich fand nur schwer aus dem Bett, denn der gestrige Tag hatte mich sehr angestrengt. Während des Rasierens fragte ich mich, was ich unternehmen sollte, und ich beschloß, baden zu gehen. Ich nahm die Straßenbahn und fuhr zur Hafenbadeanstalt. Dort schwamm ich in der schmalen Fahrrinne. Viele junge Leute waren da. Im Wasser traf ich Maria Cardona, eine frühere Stenotypistin aus meinem Büro, auf die ich damals scharf gewesen war. Sie wohl auch auf mich. Aber sie kündigte bald, und **später ist dann nichts mehr daraus geworden.**

**Question**

1. [This dictionary entry](https://www.dict.cc/?s=Es%20wurde%20nichts%20daraus) says

   > Es wurde nichts daraus

   means

   > It came to nothing.

   Am I right to think that the highlighted clause uses a form of this expression in which *es* has been suppressed?
2. Assuming yes to 1, is there any way to restore the suppressed *es* so that we get, for example:

   > später ist **es** dann nichts mehr daraus geworden

   Or is it going to sound terrible no matter where you stick in that *es* once you’ve got *später* in front of *ist*?
3. In *Es wurde nichts daraus*, do we say that *es* or *nichts* is the subject?
4. Assuming the answer to 3 is that *nichts* is the subject, then for *es regnet* do we say that it is a sentence without a subject?  Or do we resort to saying that *es* is the subject there?

**Background**

I realize that question 3 and 4 may be artificial in the sense that nothing interesting is at stake and we know what is going on without bothering our head about any subject.  But once you have a concept like *subject*, then as you come to a limiting case you can (a) say that the concept does not apply (the question is meaningless, etc.) or (b) make an arbitrary call so the concept gets a nice universal applicability.  So, questions 3 and 4 may be asking which formal choice grammarians have made.

Comment: `Später ist es dann nichts mehr daraus geworden` geht nicht, allenfalls ohne "daraus": `Später ist es dann nichts mehr geworden`. Später ist aus der Arbeitsbekanntschaft keine Affäre/Beziehung geworden. Aus dem einen  wird ein anderes - oder auch nicht.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The word *es* can have many different roles in German. In connection with certain verbs such as *regnen*, where there is no entity actually doing something, *es* can be an impersonal subject: *es regnet*. In other cases, however, it is a so-called expletive, having the purely syntactic function of filling the mandatory position before the verb. In this use, it doesn’t even have to agree with the real subject in number or gender:

> Es gingen zwei Männer die Straße entlang.
>   <s>Sie gingen zwei Männer die Straße entlang.</s>

When there is something else in first position, this *es* becomes unnecessary and vanishes:

> Im Morgengrauen gingen zwei Männer die Straße entlang.
>   Zwei Männer gingen die Straße entlang.

On the other hand, the impersonal subject with *regnen* is always there:

> Es regnete die ganze Nacht.
>   Die ganze Nacht regnete es.

The *es* in the sentence from your dictionary, *Es wurde nichts daraus*, belongs to the other category – it is an expletive that is only necessary because of the word order. When the sentence is changed into, e.g., *Daraus wurde nichts*, the *es* disappears. There is no choice involved: The *es* is required in *Es wurde nichts daraus* and can’t be used in *Daraus wurde nichts*.

Since *es* in its role as an expletive isn’t really a sentence part, it can’t be the subject – *nichts* is the only option here. (Note that in this expression, *werden* is not the auxiliary but the full verb, meaning “to come into existence”.)

As I said above, the *es* in *Es regnet* is completely different and is indeed considered the subject of that sentence.

Comment: Kann ich _Nichts wurde daraus_ sagen?

Comment: @Monsignor: Ja, aber es ist weniger verbreitet als die anderen Versionen.

Comment: @Monsignor. Yes: that puts an emphasis on the *nichts*, it is between "daraus wurde nichts" and "*gar nichts* ist daraus geworden".

Comment: +1, but you could add that ‘und es ist dann später nichts mehr daraus geworden’ would be a possible reordering that allows the expletive *es* to be present (style issues aside).